# jQuery: pushing values in .serializeArray();

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on an AJAX form submition in jQuery.

I used the `.serializeArray()` function for serializing the form, but I need to add an element to the obtained object, so I used the `push()` function.

So it may look like that:

```
{
    name: "Test",
    surname: "Test",
    action: "register"
}
```

When I serialize the form, the name and surname field will be sent, but the action field will not.
I send the informations to a PHP echo function but, like the `console.log()` result, it will show the name and the surname, but not the action.

I tried the `.serialize()` function to, but I'll still not obtain what needed.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s9ka3bp/23/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $("#register").serializeArray();
        data.push({name: "action", value: "register"});

        console.log(data);

        jQuery.post("/echo/json/", data,
            function () {
                alert("Success");
            },
        "json");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide code where you try to send the object

Comment: @Izzey, fiddle updated.

Comment: What you have should work fine.

Comment: @FelixKling I used the `.serialize()` function to, but the result still the same.

I know that I can do it "manually" via hidden elements, but I saw that other people had the same problem, but with the `.push()` function they solved their problem.

Comment: can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7s9ka3bp/12/

Comment: Based on the fiddle, the `data` isn't likely the issue. Rather that the `<form>` is still submitting normally. This causes the page to navigate and will interrupt the `jQuery.post()` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending two requests, so disable form submit:

```
$( '#register' ).on( 'submit', function() {
    return false;
});
```

Or you can just place the submit button outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are binding an event handler, but you are not preventing the form from submitting like the default behavior. You can fix this by adding `return false;` at the end of the event handler, but there are better ways (search google for jQuery prevent form submit). You also need to bind `$('#register').submit` instead of `$("#registerSubmit").click` (this makes the enter button work as well)

Comment: OP still needs to send key/value pairs to server. `serializeArray()` creates array of objects

Comment: Yeah, but the push method that he has in the fiddle works just fine (check the console.log)

Comment: understood, but it's still an array with no `key` being posted for `$_POST` to accept

Comment: Whit the submission to PHP of `.serializeArray()` works like `.serialize()`, but the problem is oh the `.push()` that isn't sent:

JSFiddle Header, Form Data:
`name=Test&surname=Test`.

The action field didn't exists.

Comment: jQuery converts it to proper form data when you pass an array as the data. Try it for yourself in the console: `jQuery.post("index.php", [{name:'a',value:'b'}],console.log,"json");`

Comment: my bad..have never tried that and didn't realize the array would get parsed properly